# OpenDialog C++ Builder

Tags: c++builder, файлы

Сохраняю данные из StringGrid в текстовый файл вот так.

```
FILE *fop=fopen(SaveDialog1->FileName.c_str(),"wt");
    if(fop)
    {
             if(nt->RowCount>0)
                 fprintf(fop,nt->Rows[0]->CommaText.c_str());
             for(int i=1;i<nt->RowCount;i++)
                 fprintf(fop,"\n%s",nt->Rows[i]->CommaText.c_str());
             fclose(fop);
    }
```

nt - это StringGrid
Как считать из файла при помощи OpenDialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы считывал не CommaText, а по Cells[i][j], тогда и обратное чтение из файла в StringGrid облегчится.
Считывайте из файла OpenDialog->FileName.c_str() с помощью:

```
while(fscanf(fop, "%s", str) != EOF)
{
  nt->Cells[i][j] = (AnsiString)str;
  ...    
}
```